# Pygame - maintain playing speed of game when keys are pressed

Tags: python, pygame

I've got a Space invaders style game which works okay but when I press a key to move my player's ship, the aliens slow down until the key is released.   This is because there's more code being run when a key is pressed than if there isn't (obviously). Here's the code that's run when I press a key

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    objShip.move(1)
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    objShip.move(2)
elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    objShip.move(3)
elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    objShip.move(4)
```

which calls the following code

```
def move(self, d):
    self.direction = d
    if self.direction == 1:
        self.image = pygame.image.load("shipu.png").convert()
        if self.yco >= 0:
            self.yco -= 1
        if self.xco >= 884:
            self.xco = 860
```

Is there a way of way of equalising the speed of the aliens which doesn't involve putting a wait command (or an empty loop or whatever) into the else statement to act as a make-work delay?

I can put all the code here but it's a bit lengthy at the moment so thought I'd try without incase there's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Why kind of movement do you intend to have? Do you want a static speed  or a varied one using acceleration?

Comment: I just want the ship to move at a fixed speed when the key is pressed (currently 1 pixel)

Comment: Then set the static speed as `self.speed = 1`. Then add or subtract from the position.

Comment: I'm doing that already, it's just hardcoded as 1 pixel, rather than adding a property of 1 pixel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("shipu.png").convert()
```

You're reloading the ships image every single time it moves. Don't do this.

Loading the image returns a surface, store that surface in the ship's object, and render that surface at the ship's coordinates every frame, never having to load the image again.

Loading files is very slow, and this is why you're seeing such a dramatic slowdown.

Considering you have multiple graphics for different movement states, load all the images at once, when you create the ship, and store their resulting surfaces in separate variables, or a dictionary. When you need to swap between graphics, just swap out the surfaces to the needed one.

Whatever you do, load all images only ONCE!

The slow down is still going to happen when you change it to the way I just suggested, but it will at least be imperceptible.
To even out movement over time, you need to use 'delta time'. Which is basically basing the distance moved off the render time.

Comment: The ship image needs to change every time so it faces the direction of travel.   I could store the previous position in another property, then check if the direction has changed, if so, update the image :S

Comment: @Glyn So load and store all the images in separate variables, or a dictionary. And select them from there. Just  whatever you do, load the images ONCE.

Comment: That's got it, it was definitely the reloading graphics that was taking the time.   I've done the same with the other graphics and that's got rid of the hiccup when firing the bullet too. Thanks

Comment: @Glyn Mark it as the answer then... :D I'll edit my answer to include my comment.